# haskell, Functor for Data Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to write functor for Tree (form of this type is given below)

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 

instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f Empty = Empty
    fmap f (Node a x y) =  Node (f a) (fmap f x) (fmap f y)
```

It seems to be working, but what about more elegant (I am newbie in haskell) solutions? 
The second issue is that lecturer wrote signature:  `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`
for me, it is `(a->b) -> Tree a ->  Tree b`, but it is not accepted by compiler ghci. Where is the point ?

Comment: If you enable the `DeriveFunctor` extension in GHC you can have the compiler derive the Functor instance for you by if you change your definition to `data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree  a) deriving (Functor)`. Your implementation is pretty standard though so I doubt you can make a more 'elegant' one yourself.

Comment: What about signature ?

Comment: I don't understand your signature problem, the type of `fmap` is `(a -> b) -> f a -> fb` which is what you have there, where `f` is `Tree`.

Comment: You answer is ok for me. Why it is written f instead of Tree ?

Comment: The `Functor` class definition states that some type constructor `f` is a functor if it implements the function `fmap`. A type constructor is a type-level function which is used to construct types, e.g. `List`, `Maybe`, `IO` etc. Those type constructors take a single argument, like your `Tree` type, and like the `f` constructor in the definition of `Functor`. Your instance for `Tree` therefore defines how `fmap` works for your `Tree` type by substituting `f` for `Tree`. So `f` is a type constructor variable in the definition of the `Functor` class.

Comment: @HaskellFun: Don't forget that Lee's signature of `fmap` is incomplete, it's missing the `Functor f =>` constraint.

Comment: By the way, your first question is better suited for [codereview.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what about more elegant [...] solutions?

It's perfectly fine. All other solutions that aren't using any helper functions will look more or less the same. The only thing I would change is the alignment of the `=`s and the names `x` and `y` as `l` and `r` (referring to the left and right branch):

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap _ Empty        = Empty
  fmap f (Node a l r) = Node (f a) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)
```

However, that's my personal opinion. Let's get to the real question, `fmap`'s type:

> The second issue is that lecturer wrote signature: `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` […]

First of all, the lecturer's signature is *somewhat* wrong. `fmap`'s complete signature is

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The constraint `Functor f` is important. It limits the use of `fmap` to the instances of `Functor`. Now that's not the problem you've encountered:

> for me, it is `(a->b) -> Tree a ->  Tree b`, but it is not accepted by compiler ghci. Where is the point?

Ah, you've tried to specify a type signature for `fmap` in the `Functor Tree` instance, right?

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
  fmap = ...
```

Well, that's not allowed. After all, `fmap`'s type *isn't* `(a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`, but the more general one above. It's somewhat—but not entirely—similar to using two type signatures for a single binding:

```
foo :: Eq a => a ->  a -> Bool
foo ::        () -> () -> Bool
```

That's not allowed either. Note that you can enable instance signatures [with an extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-sigs) if you really want to. If you just want to do it for documentation, a comment can be used instead of `-XInstanceSigs`:

```
instance Functor Tree where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
  fmap = ...
```

**TL;DR**: `fmap`'s type is given by it's declaration in `class Functor`, it's already specified by your choice of `f` in the `instance` definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is quite elegant. Another option is to define `fmap` using `traverse`:

```
import Data.Traversable

-- Preorder traversal based on the way you defined the Node constructor. Could use any traversal.
instance Traversable Tree where
  traverse _ Empty = pure Empty
  traverse f (Node v l r) = Node <$> f v <*> traverse f l <*> traverse f r 

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap = fmapDefault

instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap = foldMapDefault
```

I wouldn't say this is more elegant, but if you want all these instances, and don't want to `derive` them it's a pithy way to do it.